# How to slow down manually-controlled rotation of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, three.js

as in the title, could somebody help me how to slow down mouse-controlled rotation of a 3D object in javascript? The rotation is simply too sensitive and hard to control manually. Here is the code I have:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/ColladaLoader.js"></script>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script></head>
<body>
<script>
    // Set up the scene, camera, and renderer as global variables.
  var scene, camera, renderer, mesh;

  init();
  animate();

// Sets up the scene.
  function init() {

    // Create the scene and set the scene size.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x999999 ) );
    var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
        HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

// Create a renderer and add it to the DOM.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


 // Create a camera, zoom it out from the model a bit, and add it to the scene.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT,1,1000);
    camera.position.z = 100;
    scene.add(camera);


 // Create an event listener that resizes the renderer with the browser window.
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
          HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
      renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    });

// Set the background color of the scene.
    renderer.setClearColor(0x333F47, 1);

    // Create a light, set its position, and add it to the scene.
    var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.6);
    pointLight.position.set(80,90,150);
    scene.add(pointLight);


 // Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load( "models/water.dae", function(result){
      //geometry.computeBoundingBox();
      //var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial;
      //mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      result.scene.scale.x = .01;
      result.scene.scale.y = .01;
      result.scene.scale.z = .01;
      result.scene.position.z = 20; // We are looking towards negative z axis in openGL (right hand coordinate in world space), -z axis goes inside screen but since we placed camera position to be at z = 100, we can place on positive z-axis
      result.scene.updateMatrix();
      result.scene.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
      scene.add(result.scene);
    });


 // Add OrbitControls so that we can pan around with the mouse.
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    controls.enableZoom = true;
    controls.target.z = 20;

  }


// Renders the scene and updates the render as needed.
  function animate() {

    // Read more about requestAnimationFrame at http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    // Render the scene.
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();

  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any comments/suggestions.

Comment: Your question is NOT about the Java3D API, please refrain yourself from using abusively this tag.

Comment: @gouessej This is their first post.  Rather than accusing them of abuse, you might want to politely explain why the tag was not appropriate here.  If one types "3d" into the tagging system that tag is one of the top responses.  A new user could easily make a mistake rather than engaging in abuse as you have suggested.

Comment: JavaScript and Java are two distinct programming languages. Three.js and Java3D are two distinct APIs. As the original poster used the "javascript" tag, he knew that Three.js is a JavaScript API and not a Java API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "slow down" mouse movement since you say it is too sensitive. Is the rotation going faster than it should or is it just following the mouse too quickly?

To slow down mouse controlled rotation, you could use an easing equation to make it smoother, if that's what you're asking. One I find myself using often (for 2d that is) is the following:

```
rotation += (targetRotation - rotation) / speed;
```

So if I wanted an object to rotate towards my mouse at a slow speed, I'd write the following:

```
object.rotation += (mouseRotation - object.rotation) / 15;
```

I'm sure you could adapt this to a 3d system.

Comment: Flizzet, very much appreciated. Yes, indeed. I meant slow down mouse controlled rotation, when you drag and rotate a 3D model on the screen.